# How to get image path of an image stored using Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Tags: android, file, uri

Hi I successfully stored and get image using following code 
To store image

```
FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(picName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                compressed_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, bos);
                byte[] img = bos.toByteArray();
                fos.write(img);
                fos.close();
```

To get image

```
InputStream input = getActivity().openFileInput(imageName);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input,null,null);
```

but also i need to know the path.How to get the path where the image is stored.Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method in your fragment

```
String absolutePath = getActivity().getFileStreamPath(imageName);
```